# Samsung S3 external hard drive 2TB on Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: partitioning, usb, mount, hard-drive, external-hdd

It acts very strange on Ubuntu as well on Slackware...

When I type `lsusb` it return me this:

```
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 04e8:6031 Samsung Electronics Co., Ltd 
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 003: ID 148f:3070 Ralink Technology, Corp. RT2870/RT3070 Wireless Adapter
Bus 003 Device 002: ID 1d57:fa60 Xenta 
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

3th line is Samsung hard disk...

But when I type:

`sude fdisk -l`

It just show this:

```
Device          Start        End    Sectors  Size Type
/dev/sda1        2048    1050623    1048576  512M EFI System
/dev/sda2     1050624 5843892223 5842841600  2.7T Linux filesystem
/dev/sda3  5843892224 5860532223   16640000    8G Linux swap
```

and FREEZ never show `sdb` partitions from external hard disk...

Also If I try to mount partition `sdb` it just freez...

`dmesg | tail -n 20` command retuns this:

```
[99366.426812]  [<ffffffff8124ae00>] __blkdev_put+0x80/0x290
[99366.426816]  [<ffffffff8124b4bc>] blkdev_put+0x4c/0x110
[99366.426819]  [<ffffffff8124b5b4>] blkdev_close+0x34/0x70
[99366.426823]  [<ffffffff81210744>] __fput+0xe4/0x220
[99366.426827]  [<ffffffff812108be>] ____fput+0xe/0x10
[99366.426831]  [<ffffffff8109efc1>] task_work_run+0x81/0xa0
[99366.426835]  [<ffffffff81083f91>] do_exit+0x2e1/0xb00
[99366.426840]  [<ffffffff81229c69>] ? generic_update_time+0x79/0xd0
[99366.426843]  [<ffffffff81084833>] do_group_exit+0x43/0xb0
[99366.426847]  [<ffffffff810909b2>] get_signal+0x292/0x600
[99366.426851]  [<ffffffff8102e567>] do_signal+0x37/0x6f0
[99366.426854]  [<ffffffff8124a6f5>] ? blkdev_read_iter+0x35/0x40
[99366.426859]  [<ffffffff8100320c>] exit_to_usermode_loop+0x8c/0xd0
[99366.426862]  [<ffffffff81003c6e>] syscall_return_slowpath+0x4e/0x60
[99366.426866]  [<ffffffff81838750>] int_ret_from_sys_call+0x25/0x8f
[99402.393038] sd 10:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#0 FAILED Result: hostbyte=DID_OK driverbyte=DRIVER_SENSE
[99402.393043] sd 10:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#0 Sense Key : Not Ready [current] 
[99402.393046] sd 10:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#0 Add. Sense: Logical unit is in process of becoming ready
[99402.393050] sd 10:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#0 CDB: Read(10) 28 00 00 03 ff a2 00 00 08 00
[99402.393052] blk_update_request: I/O error, dev sdb, sector 262050
```

On Windows OS everthing works fine. Anyone know what is a problem with Linux systems?

Comment: What file system?

Comment: Think FAT32, but can see with mount command bacause it not list `sdb`...

Comment: There is some issue with the disk. Maybe it needs more power (try different USB port or active powered USB HUB).

Comment: It is not problem with USB port becaouse it working on Win 8

Comment: It either has an unsupported file system (eg. exFAT, not FAT32 for a 2TB drive), or it has been set as "dynamic" in Windows, or the interface controller has issues with Linux. If you can use with Windows then please check the file system, use the error correction tool... Then, if new data, update your question.